# Check to see if a Google form has a destination spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google apps script to get information from a form, but I am thinking that it is a good Idea to check and see if the form already has a destination spreadsheet attached to it.  If it does I want to grab the ID if it does not I want to create one.  Every time I run the code below The de-bugger throws an error telling me "The form currently has no response destination."

Please help

```
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formName = form.getTitle();


    function randomQuestion() {
      var theFormID = form.getId();

      var sheetID = function sheetID() {

      if ( form.getDestinationId() === 'undefined' ) {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(formName + ' (Responses)');
          form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
          return form.getDestinationId();

      }else {
       return form.getDestinationId();}

      }
    var sheet = sheetID();
    g;  // <-un-comment this to make the de-bugger throw an error =)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Code that I used to test if there is a Response Spreadsheet and if not create one.

```
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formName = form.getTitle();
    var ssID;

    try {
      ssID = form.getDestinationId();
    }
    catch(e) {
      var exception = e.name;
      if (exception === "Exception" ){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(formName + ' (Responses)');
        form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
        ssID = form.getDestinationId();
      }else{
        ssID = form.getDestinationId();
      }
    }
```

Comment: why did you have another else condition to that if? which does the same thing? i am thinking to use this without that

Answer (score 2):

The method `getDestinationId()` throws an exception when the form has no response destination. You need to handle this with a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), something like:

```
...
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(), idResponse;
try {
  idResponse = form.getDestinationId();
}
catch(e) {
  // TODO
}
...
```

Comment: That should be reported as a bug!

Comment: At least, the documentation should be more specific and indicate that the method can throw an exception. This is done in other methods, e.g. [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app?hl=en#openById(String)) and [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app?hl=en#openByUrl(String))

Comment: Thank you this worked...and I learned something!  Here is the Code that I used to test if there is a Spreadsheet and if not create one.
`code`
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ssID;

try {
  ssID = form.getDestinationId();
}
catch(e) {
  var exception = e.name;
  if (exception === "Exception" ){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(formName + ' (Responses)');
    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
    ssID = form.getDestinationId();
  }else{
    ssID = form.getDestinationId();
  }
}`code`

Comment: @Mogsdad: I found the reported issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760106. Starred.